# SSH to my company's server

Tags: networking, ssh, ip, dynamic-dns

So I am working from home and I need to connect(SSH) to my company's server ever yday.

The problem is that they have recently done an IP lockdown and only selected IPs can connect.
My IP is not static/sticky and it changes every couple of days.

My current ISP won't offer static IP unless I buy business package and then on the top of that pay for static IP - they think that static IPs are only for companies :(.

So is there any workaround this problem?

Comment: If they have blocked access only to a specific series of IPs you would need to get on this list. Depending on your ISP policy you might find they only change it once every 6 months or more (you can check this), if it's frequent there isn't a lot you can do other than buy business.

Comment: They blocked all IPs and they have a whitelist. The whitelist holds all the IPs of the workers that can connect. Currently I have to phone them whenever my IP changes and give them my new IP which is quite annoying

Comment: If you need this for work, then surely you can expense the cost back to your company?  If they are unwilling to cover the cost, then simply do not bother logging in.

Comment: Depending on your company IT policy you can look at various Dynamic IP email alert systems which can keep them updated and possibly add your new IP to their list automatically if they are willing to code this in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also get a cheap VPS for a couple of $ per year and use that to tunnel the connection through (or just do ssh-through-ssh). This way you'll get a fixed IP.

You can find a list of cheap providers at http://lowendbox.com/

Answer (score 0):

You may either follow @mtak's advice and configure reversed SSH tunnel via some chip external host with static public IP, or ask your employer to configure smth like port-knocking.